# Get variable from another conditional block

Tags: php, forms

I want to get a variable from a conditional if of form assigned to take the value of a textbox:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit" value="Click Here!" name="submit">
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            echo "<br /><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Show it!\" name=\"show\">";
        }

        if (isset($_POST['show'])) {
            echo $name; //i got "Notice: Undefined variable: name" here
        }
    ?>
</form>
```

I want show value of `$name` after input:name pressed.

Comment: Move the declaration of the variable before your first if conditional (or move it inside your second if). But I don't think the code is correct in its entirety (two submit buttons).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and welcome to stackoverflow,

If you want to make your form in 2 steps, you need to store the "name" value in the intermediate form.

```
<form action="" method="POST">                                                                                             
    <input type="text" name="name">                                                                                        
    <input type="submit" value="Click Here!" name="submit">                                                                
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $name = htmlentities($_POST['name']);
        echo "<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"{$name}\" name=\"name\">";
        echo "<br /><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Show it!\" name=\"show\">";
    }

    if (isset($_POST['show']))
    {
        $name = htmlentities($_POST['name']);
        echo $name;
    }
    ?>                                                                                                                     
</form>
```

Several things to point out :

- in a  field of type "hidden" you store your $name
- in such a way you can recover it in the second step
- you should also have a look to the [htmlentities()](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) function

Hope this helps!

## Try it [here](http://temp.ocarina.fr/form.php)

Answer (score 1):

This should solve the issue

```
    $name = "";

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        echo "<br /><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Show it!\" name=\"show\">";
    }

    if (isset($_POST['show'])) {
        echo $name;
    }
```

The problem in your code is that the scope of `$name` is limited to the first if

Comment: By the way, I am not sure why you are outputting another submit, but that is another issue

Comment: How about i change to outputting another form contained submit, can be better way?

Comment: @Bakti Elvian: it really depends what you are trying to achieve. I would personally just use JS to show/hide some text, no need to resubmit the page